# PHP Variable Variable in Function

Tags: php, variables

i've been wondering how this could be done, i've got a function.

```
  $sky = (a range of number 1 to 10);


function condi($nnn){ 
  if($$nnn <= 1){
  echo 'Fails';
  }
  elseif($$nnn <= 3){
  echo 'Respectable';
  }
  elseif($$nnn <= 5){
  echo 'Decent';
  }
  elseif($$nnn <= 7){
  echo 'Great';
  }
  elseif($$nnn <= 9){
  echo 'Legendary';
  }
  elseif($$nnn = 10){
  echo 'Ultimate';
  }
 }

  condi('sky');
```

But no matter what is the value of $sky, the output is fails.

So i decided to check what is the value of $$nnn, then i realized that the $$nnn doesn't have a value in it. Any help please?

Comment: Variable variables are horrible. Don't use them.

Comment: If you really want a variable variable/dynamic variable you could write: ${$nnn}  to make it more clear what you're really trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `$$nnn` with `$GLOBALS[$nnn]`.

Whatever variable name `$nnn` contains - it's not local to the function so you need to acess it via the `$GLOBALS` array (which is much cleaner than doing something like `global $$nnn;` and then using `$$nnn`).

Comment: +1 I upvoted both this and `global $$nnn;` as they are both valid solutions, but you're right, this is cleaner (as long as the variable is brought to the inner scope, using `$GLOBALS[$nnn]` everywhere would be an eyesore :-)

Comment: @rudi_visser What's the difference between `global $$nnn;` and aliasing like `$$nn = $GLOBALS[$nnn];` How is one cleaner than the other. I've been using `global $o;` to import global scoped variables (not that I use them much) for a long time :S

Comment: Thanks, still pretty new to PHP :) Works well!

Comment: @PaulPRO Some people see `global` as a (excuse me) bastardisation of programming like `goto`. I'm not exactly one of them, but where possible I do believe it is better to encapsulate functions that rely on external variables in classes of their own, where you can import everything you need in a way that makes sense. What I meant by aliasing the variable is doing something such as: `function name($varname) { $var = $GLOBALS[$varname]; switch($var) { /* .. */ } }` as it's simply cleaner. Variable-variables can be confusing at best of times.. But I think it's mainly down to personal preference :)

Comment: @PaulPro also of course, using `GLOBALS` allows you to have a variable called `$$name` (ie. `$sky`) internally aswell! But still, I think the key point is to avoid globals whereever possible.

Answer (score 2):

`$sky` is in the global scope:

```
function condi($nnn){ 
  global $$nnn;
  if($$nnn <= 1){
    ...
```

Comment: No, you're making it even worse. He doesn't want a global, he just wants to pass an argument to it's function (otherwise the 'function' would be no use).

Comment: @Robert He wants to pass a variable name to the function, and utilise that variable (in global scope) from within the function. It's a silly requirement, but this will resolve his issue.

Comment: @Robert de W How so? He is passing a string to a function which tells the function which global variable he wants to use.

Comment: @PaulPRO; You're right, he does. I made the above conclusion too soon in answering the question.

Answer (score 0):

In order for the function to see `$sky` (which i'm presuming is the goal), it must be visible in the function's scope.  Globals aren't visible by default.

You'll need to either say `global $$nnn;` inside your function, or change `$$nnn` to `$GLOBALS[$nnn]` instead.  And note, this will only work for globals -- you won't be able to pass the names of other functions' locals and have this function see them.

Answer (score -1):

You have two $$ signs in your "nnn" variable. Delete one.

Answer (score -1):

you should use

```
<?php
$sky = rand(1, 5);
function condi($nnn){
    global $sky;
    switch ($$nnn) {
        case $$nnn < 1:
            echo "Fails";
            break;
        case $$nnn < 3:
            echo "Respectable";
            break;
        case $$nnn <= 5:
            echo "Decent";
            break;
        // .................... //
    }
}
condi('sky');
?>
```

Comment: `global $sky;` defeats the purpose of a variable variable if you have to know what it's going to contain in advance.